# Keras doesn't find GPU, how to change that?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gpu

I am trying to build a simple NN with keras. I have 2 GPUs on my machine:

[image]

But Keras doesn't seem to recognize any of them:

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Any ideas?

I am using python 3.9, tensorflow 2.11, keras 2.11.

Comment: Have you followed the installation instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions)? In particular, did you install `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn` prior to installing tensorflow?

Comment: Also, if you are installing natively on Windows, see the note: "Caution: TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin"

Comment: @MattPitkin Just needed to follow the instructions and install the TensorFlow-GPU package. Thank you very very much!!